# Prove Every Axiom Instance Has A Property

Tags: logic, induction, propositional-calculus

Consider an axiom form $\phi \rightarrow \phi$. I need to show that every instance of this has an even number of $\neg$'s.

I'm not sure how to proceed.

Here is what I've tried. I've assumed some arbitrary instance of the schema since I'm trying to show that universal claim is true. And since the instance, $P \rightarrow P$ has 0 negations and 0 is an even number, it has 0 negations. And as $P \rightarrow P$ was arbitrary then even instance of $\phi \rightarrow \phi$ has an even number of negations.

Does that sound right? Is there another way to proceed? Any tips or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: If $P$ is supposed to be an atomic formula then you've proven one (of several) cases. If $P$ is meant to be an arbitrary formula, then it's the same question you are trying to prove.

Comment: What are the other cases? I mean $P$ to be an arbitrary instance of the schema $\phi \rightarrow \phi$, as per $\forall$ introduction.

Comment: Any other formula whatsoever, e.g. $\neg P$, $P\land Q$, et cetera, et cetera. The exact list will depend on exactly which (primitive) connectives your particular formal presentation has.

Comment: So, how would I go about showing that every instance of that schema has an even number of negations if by not doing a $\forall$ introduction, and flagging some arbitrary instance?

Comment: How do you prove something is true for all natural numbers? Your current proof attempt is like proving all integers are non-negative by assuming an arbitrary integer $x$ and noting there is no negative sign so it must be non-negative.

Comment: Weak mathematical induction. But my question is about how I go about doing a structural inductive proof on theorems for the claim that an axiomatic system with the axiom schema $\phi \rightarrow \phi$ has an even number of $\neg$s. I'm trying to work out the Base Step of the structural  inductive proof.

Comment: And weak mathematical induction is exactly structural induction on the naturals. Note that the proof rule for it is $P(0)\land(\forall n.P(n)\to P(n+1))\to\forall n.P(n)$ so we just apply the rule and get a universal statement, we don't need to apply universal generalization. This is true for inductively-defined structures in general: to prove something about all elements of them, you use structural induction. The statement in your question is a perfectly fine argument for the base case of the structural induction. Now you need to do the inductive cases.

Comment: I dont get it, if there are $n$ negations in $\phi$, then there are $2n$ negations in $\phi\to\phi$.

Comment: Oh oh. Thank you so much. The Inductive Step is to show that if $\theta$ has an even number of negations and so does $\theta \rightarrow \psi$ then so does $\psi.$ 

So, I need to assume the antecedent as my inductive hypothesis.

Do you have a tip or suggestion about how I derive that $\psi$ thereby has an even number of negations? I'm trying via RAA but it's not quite working out.

Comment: @Rusty Induction is total overkill and unncessarily complicated. Just look at Rene Schipperus' comment!

Comment: Thanks for everything, team, but I need to know how to do the overkill. That's why I'm struggling through it and asking for some tips.

Comment: @Rusty An example inductive case would be $\varphi=\psi\land\chi$ where $\psi\to\psi$ and $\chi\to\chi$ are assumed to have an even number of negations and you need to prove $(\psi\land\chi)\to(\psi\land\chi)$ has an even number of negations. Rene Schipperus' approach works but hides the structural induction in the properties of the function that counts the number of occurrences of $\neg$ (which is completely fine for a typical informal proof). (As an aside, the whole statement could actually be false if $\varphi\to\psi$ was simply an abbrevation for $\neg\varphi\lor\psi$, say.)

Answer (score 0):

How many $\phi$ are in ($\phi$$\rightarrow$$\phi$)?  Note that any instance of ($\phi$$\rightarrow$$\phi$) has that many instances of $\phi$ in it.  Also, note that 0 is even.